# NetLogo GIS: How to create random points on Map

Tags: gis, netlogo, shapefile, arcgis-js-api

I have loaded a shapefile of certain city into Netlogo successfully using the GIS extension as shown below.

[image]

with the following code

```
    extensions [ gis ]
    globals [ countries-dataset min-map max-map]
    patches-own [ mapa ]
to setup
 reset-ticks
  clear-turtles
  clear-patches
  clear-drawing
  clear-all-plots
  clear-output
  ; Note that setting the coordinate system here is optional, as
  ; long as all of your datasets use the same coordinate system.
  ; Load all of our datasets

  ; Load the dataset


  set countries-dataset gis:load-dataset "city.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-union-of (gis:envelope-of countries-dataset))
  gis:set-drawing-color green
  gis:draw countries-dataset 1

  reset-ticks
end

to match-cells-to-patches
  cd
  ct
end

to startup
  setup
end
```

How does one create random turtles along roads *only*?

Comment: this question is better suited for gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RickyA Actually, this is very specifically a NetLogo question, not a GIS question so should stay in SO. `turtles` will mean absolutely nothing to a GIS person.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want turtles to be along the roads, or you also want them to move along the roads?

For the former, try `gis:find-features` and `gis:vertex-lists-of` to get all vertices in the graph, and choose a random one (this will limit the location to vertex only). If you want location to be somewhere on the straight line section, you can calculate a point between two consecutive vertices.